# Run shell script when Alacritty starts

Tags: macos, shell, alacritty

I'm on macOS Monterrey 12.6.1 with Homebrew installed Alacritty.

I want to run a script when Alacritty launches, `echo Hello!`

I have this in my alacritty.yml config. But it doesn't work:

```
shell:
  program: /bin/zsh
  args:
    - -c "/full/path/to/myScript/hello.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Problem, and I was able to solve it by passing the `--login` flag to `zsh`. To my understanding, you need to load your environment to execute your script, which is not done automatically. My solution is:

```yaml
shell: /bin/zsh
args:
    - --login
    - -c
    - /full/path/to/your/script.sh
```

I hope it solves your Problem.